# Htaccess + mod_rewrite doesnt work when file exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to redirect all images to .php file.

put in .htaccess this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$ images/w/index.php?image=$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

it works only when file doesnt exists

for example i have uploaded file qwe.jpg to the root folder of my site.

then i go http://mysite_com/qwe.jpg - redirect doesnt work, i see my jpg file

when i go http://mysite_com/qwe1.jpg (qwe1.jpg doesnt exist) - redirect works, i see what i have wrote in images/w/index.php!

how to make it works with existed files?

Comment: There is no apparent reason why this should treat existing files differently. This _can_ be checked for using a RewriteCond, but there don’t appear to be any here. Are you sure this was not just your browser cache tricking you? Delete your browsing history, or test in a private window.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure, tried different times and browsers, incognito mode, etc...